# Is it Halal to record your own masturbation video and see it secretly after uploading it to a well-protected cloud account?

Tags: halal-haram, pornography

Is it Halal to record your own masturbation video or capture a photo of your own naked body and see it secretly after uploading it to a well-protected cloud account?

Answer (score 1):

Is pornographie halal?
Is masturbation halal?
Is it permitted to publish any naked picture?

Triple no.

Under such condition, there can't be an if condition that makes it halal.